# http post xml document to webservice c# return error 500

Tags: web-services

help me
I http post a xml document to methos webservice:

> POST XML USING POSTMAN:

```
<ACCESSGW>
<MODULE>SMSMO_NOTIFIER</MODULE>
<MESSAGE_TYPE>NOTIFY</MESSAGE_TYPE>
<COMMAND>
    <queueID>3799706</queueID>
    <msisdn>84912555757</msisdn>
    <cpURL>https://www.google.com.vn/</cpURL>
    <channel>SMS</channel>
    <price>1000</price>
    <moID>27683</moID>
    <commandcode>DK</commandcode>
    <short_code>6713</short_code>
    <expiredTime>20180326102947</expiredTime>
    <cpID>1</cpID>
    <cpcode>MEDIA</cpcode>
</COMMAND>
</ACCESSGW>
```

> GET METHOD C#

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument NOITIFI_SMSMO(string queueID,string msisdn,string cpURL,string channel, string price, string moID, string commandcode, string short_code, string expiredTime, string cpID, string cpcode)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    SmsAutoRecv smsAutoRecv = new SmsAutoRecv();
    smsAutoRecv.queueID = queueID;
    doc.LoadXml("<ACCESSGW>0</ACCESSGW>");
    return doc; 
}
```

however,

> ERROR RETURN
>   soap:VersionMismatchSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CheckHelperVersion() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)

Comment: <faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode>

Comment: PLS, HELP ME HELP ME